# Homotopy class of almost complex structures

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $M^{2n}$ be a smooth orientable manifold. The tangent bundle $TM$ of $M$ is induced by a classifying map $f:M\to BSO(2n)$ which is unique up to homotopy. An almost complex structure on $M$ is a homotopy class $[\tilde{f}]$ of a lift $\tilde{f}:M\to BU(n)$ of $f$ to $BU(n)$.

Let $\tilde{f}_1,\tilde{f}_2\in [\tilde{f}]$ be two lifts in the same homotopy class and $F:[0,1]\times M \to BU(n)$ a homotopy from $\tilde{f}_1$ to $\tilde{f}_2$.

**Question:** Is $F(t,\cdot):M\to BU(n)$ an almost complex structure on $M$ for all $t\in [0,1]$?

Comment: Do you have any assumptions about $F$ at all, besides that it is a homomopy from $J$ to $J'$?  This is very obviously false without some assumptions (for instance, $F(t,\cdot)$ may not even be a map of vector bundles for some $t$).

Comment: For instance, if $M=\mathbb{C}^n$ then $TM$ is contractible so a homotopy from $J$ to $J'$ could pass through any map $TM\to TM$ at all.

Comment: ...but then again, since $M=\mathbb{C}^n$ is contractible, with trivial tangent bundle, any map $M\rightarrow BU(n)$ is trivial, and thus a lift of $t_M$.

Comment: What is your definition of a homotopy of complex structures? Given your comments, it should be a homotopy class of maps $F:I\times M\rightarrow BU(n)$ such that $F_i=\tilde{t}_i$, $i=0,1$, but this is not how you have stated it.

Comment: @Tyrone: Thank you for your correction. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Then yes, with a technicality. If $Bj:BU(n)\rightarrow BSO(2n)$ is the map classifying the inclusion, then $Bj\circ F$ is a homotopy $t_M\sim t_M$. Thus for each $t\in I$, the map $F_t$ provides an almost complex structure on the pullback bundle $(Bj\circ F_t)^*E_{SO(n)}$, which is bundle-isomorphic over $M$ to $TM$, however not strictly equal to it. Fixing a suitable isomorphism will give you an almost complex structure on $TM$ (and this can be done continuously in $t$, with some care).